# set only lower bound of a limit for ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to only set the lower bound of a limit for continuous scale? I want to make all my plots 0 based without needing to specify the upper limit bound.

e.g.

```
+ scale_y_continuous(minlim=0)
```

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You can use `expand_limits`

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point() + expand_limits(y=0)
```

Here is a comparison of the two:

- without `expand_limits`

[image]

- with `expand_limits`

[image]

As of version 1.0.0 of `ggplot2`, you can specify only one limit and have the other be as it would be normally determined by setting that second limit to `NA`. This approach will allow for both expansion and truncation of the axis range.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, NA))
```

[image]

specifying it via `ylim(c(0, NA))` gives an identical figure.

Comment: @PatrickT Did you mean that as a comment to http://stackoverflow.com/q/27028825/892313?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 11):

How about using `aes(ymin=0)`, as in:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point() + aes(ymin=0)
```

Comment: This overrides the ymin for geom_errorbar, etc.; expand_limits() seems safer.

Comment: This is not universal, as for a ``geom_density`` it gives me ``Error: stat_bin() must not be used with a y aesthetic`` or when placed inside the ``geom_density``, ``Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: ymin`` (the latter being fully expected)

Comment: `aes(ymin=o)` does not set the minimum of the vertical axis. This is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 9):

You can also try the following code which will give you the min y-axis at zero and also without the extra gap between x-axis and min y value.

```
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, NA), expand = c(0,0))
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with `coord_cartesian()` instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to keep the upper extent of the scale "unchanged" from what ggplot would have calculated by default, *AND* eliminate the padding on the lower bound so the plot area starts at exactly 0, as of ggplot2 v3.0.0+ you can specify separate expansion values for the upper and lower limit of the scales.

`scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, NA), expand = expansion(mult=c(0, 0.05)))`

see the description of the limits and expand arguments in the [help](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_continuous.html) for  `scale_continuous()`,

> Use the convenience function expansion() to generate the values for the expand argument. The defaults are to expand the scale by 5% on each side for continuous variables, and by 0.6 units on each side for discrete variables.

we use the `mult` argument to `expansion()` to calculate the 5% expansion.

### Examples

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point() +
  labs(subtitle="default")
```

[image: default plot]

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, NA))+
  labs(subtitle="specifying limits alone leaves default 5% padding on both ends")
```

[image: limits-alone]

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, NA), expand=expansion(mult=c(0, 0.05))) +
  labs(subtitle = "limits and an unequal expansion gets what we're after")
```

[image: limits-and-expansion]

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can do this directly. But as a work-around, you can mimic the way that ggplot2 determines the upper limit:

```
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, max(mydata$y) * 1.1))
```