# How to handle yaxs in geom_bar in ggplot2?

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a `geom_bar` with:

```
ma.at.vs.t.duh + geom_bar(stat="bin", fill="white", colour="black", width=.2) +
ggtitle("Mandant 10 und 50") + 
theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.6, face="bold")) + 
xlab("Vertragsart") + 
ylab("Anzahl und %") +
theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=0.5, size=14), axis.text.x=element_text(size=8)) +
stat_bin(aes(label=..count..), geom="text", size=4, vjust=-0.5) +
stat_bin(aes(label = paste(sprintf("%.02f %%", ..count../sum(..count..)*100))), geom="text", size=3, vjust=-2.0)
```

How can I set `y-Axis` starting at `0` (zero). I don't need the "US-space" ;-)
Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/11214012/903061

Comment: Thank you. Where should I put expand_limits(y=0) in my code?