# How to set just one limit for axes in ggplot2 with facets?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This question is similar to this one: [How to set limits for axes in ggplot2 R plots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606697/how-to-set-limits-for-axes-in-ggplot2-r-plots), with the difference that I want to limit *one side only* (e.g. plot only for x>0 instead of   -5000 < x < 5000 )
and do it with `facets`.

Note, I'd like to know solutions for both of these simple cases:

1. `scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-5000, 5000))` ( the same as`xlim(-5000, 5000)`) - it removes points entirely from consideration (e.g. they will not be used for `geom_smooth())`
2. `coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-5000, 5000))` functions - it simply does not plot them (but still uses for  `geom_smooth())`

This situation happens often when you use `facet_wrap(~veg, scales = "free_x)` and don't know what the upper x limit for each facet, but you know that they are always positive.

Comment: You should include an example, presumably where different facets should end up with different max values (otherwise it's trivial).

Comment: just set limits = c(-5000, NA) . This works for both coord and scales function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [set only lower bound of a limit for ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214012/set-only-lower-bound-of-a-limit-for-ggplot)

Comment: Simplest answer here is already in the comments above: @Tjebo, you should post it.  Works like a charm.

Comment: @chemdork123 cheers. Answer added

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set limits one-sided with NA. Works both in `coord_` and `scale_` functions

I generally prefer coord_ because it does not remove data. For the example below you would additionally need to remove the margin at 0, e.g. with expand.

```r
library(ggplot2)    

carrots <- data.frame(length = rnorm(500000, 10000, 10000))
cukes <- data.frame(length = rnorm(50000, 10000, 20000))
carrots$veg <- 'carrot'
cukes$veg <- 'cuke'
vegLengths <- rbind(carrots, cukes)

ggplot(vegLengths, aes(length, fill = veg)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, NA))
#> Warning: Removed 94542 rows containing non-finite values (stat_density).
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(vegLengths, aes(length, fill = veg)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.2) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, NA))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

remove the margin with expand. Also one sided possible. the right margin is set to the default mult expansion of 0.05 for continous axis.

```
ggplot(vegLengths, aes(length, fill = veg)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.05))) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, NA))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```r
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, max(x)))
```

This will set the lower limit to zero, and the upper limit to the maximum of your data. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: This is what I used eventually with facets. Thanks!

Comment: I get the message 'object x not found'. Is there a way to avoid using max(data$var) and actually use x?