# Can you force the y axis to start at 0 when there is only 0's in the data (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis, facet

I am doing some data exploration which includes plotting up timeseries. When I pull the data down there a few "results" that are true zeros. The plots contain numerous sites, so I use the `facet_wrap` utility of ggplot to quickly make figures of the same parameter of interest across many sites. I found that I can force the y axes to start at 0 from [this stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214012/set-only-lower-bound-of-a-limit-for-ggplot), but when there is nothing but the zero value it reverts to a negative y axis.

Here's some code, one site has zero's and non-zero data (works) and the other has just a single zero and results in the negative y axis.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- structure(list(result = c(0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0), date = structure(c(7755, 
7769, 7783, 7796, 7832, 7888, 7888, 841), class = "Date"), param_name = c("TP_mgL", 
"TP_mgL", "TP_mgL", "TP_mgL", "TP_mgL", "TP_mgL", "TP_mgL", "TP_mgL"
), shortname = c("Black R. Boonville", "Black R. Boonville", 
"Black R. Boonville", "Black R. Boonville", "Black R. Boonville", 
"Black R. Boonville", "Black R. Boonville", "Independence R."
)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), na.action = structure(c(`4` = 4L, `5` = 5L, `7` = 7L, `8` = 8L, 
`9` = 9L, `11` = 11L, `12` = 12L, `13` = 13L, `14` = 14L, `21` = 21L, 
`23` = 23L, `24` = 24L, `25` = 25L, `27` = 27L, `32` = 32L, `36` = 36L, 
`53` = 53L, `54` = 54L, `55` = 55L, `57` = 57L, `58` = 58L, `60` = 60L, 
`61` = 61L, `64` = 64L, `65` = 65L, `68` = 68L, `69` = 69L, `70` = 70L, 
`72` = 72L, `73` = 73L, `85` = 85L, `104` = 104L, `105` = 105L, 
`109` = 109L, `110` = 110L, `123` = 123L, `127` = 127L, `129` = 129L, 
`130` = 130L, `135` = 135L, `136` = 136L, `137` = 137L, `138` = 138L, 
`141` = 141L, `143` = 143L, `144` = 144L, `145` = 145L, `146` = 146L, 
`151` = 151L, `153` = 153L, `154` = 154L, `155` = 155L, `156` = 156L, 
`157` = 157L, `161` = 161L, `164` = 164L, `165` = 165L, `166` = 166L, 
`172` = 172L, `178` = 178L, `179` = 179L, `184` = 184L, `208` = 208L, 
`209` = 209L, `257` = 257L, `264` = 264L, `268` = 268L, `287` = 287L, 
`292` = 292L, `293` = 293L, `295` = 295L, `296` = 296L, `297` = 297L, 
`304` = 304L, `320` = 320L, `329` = 329L, `330` = 330L, `331` = 331L, 
`332` = 332L, `333` = 333L, `334` = 334L, `335` = 335L, `336` = 336L, 
`337` = 337L, `338` = 338L, `339` = 339L, `340` = 340L, `341` = 341L, 
`343` = 343L, `344` = 344L, `349` = 349L, `350` = 350L, `351` = 351L, 
`365` = 365L, `371` = 371L, `374` = 374L, `378` = 378L, `383` = 383L, 
`390` = 390L, `391` = 391L, `397` = 397L, `400` = 400L, `401` = 401L, 
`402` = 402L, `410` = 410L, `412` = 412L, `413` = 413L, `414` = 414L, 
`415` = 415L, `416` = 416L, `417` = 417L, `418` = 418L, `419` = 419L, 
`421` = 421L, `422` = 422L, `424` = 424L, `425` = 425L, `430` = 430L, 
`431` = 431L, `446` = 446L, `451` = 451L, `452` = 452L, `457` = 457L, 
`458` = 458L, `459` = 459L, `463` = 463L, `470` = 470L, `480` = 480L, 
`493` = 493L, `494` = 494L, `496` = 496L, `498` = 498L, `499` = 499L, 
`500` = 500L, `501` = 501L, `506` = 506L, `507` = 507L, `508` = 508L, 
`512` = 512L, `513` = 513L, `514` = 514L, `515` = 515L, `516` = 516L, 
`539` = 539L, `563` = 563L, `564` = 564L, `565` = 565L, `569` = 569L, 
`570` = 570L, `571` = 571L, `574` = 574L, `575` = 575L, `581` = 581L, 
`587` = 587L, `593` = 593L, `600` = 600L, `605` = 605L, `610` = 610L, 
`750` = 750L, `761` = 761L, `776` = 776L, `837` = 837L, `855` = 855L, 
`861` = 861L, `881` = 881L), class = "omit"))

ggplot(dat) +
  geom_point(aes(x=date,y=result,color=param_name),
             pch=19) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,NA)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(element_blank()) +
  facet_wrap(facets = ~shortname,
             scales = 'free')  +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = '%y') +
  theme(legend.position = 'none') +
  xlab('Year') +
  ylab(expression(paste('Total Phosphorus (',mu,'/g/l)')))
```

[image]

I've tried the `expand_limits(y=0)` and `scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,NA))` and neither forces that single zero plot to start at 0. Wondering if there is any way to achieve this?

**EDIT**
Thanks to Seth's comment I realized a pitfall of my question. In the actual data the data ranges enough in the y-direction such that I need to keep the y-scale free. Seth's nice solution of only freeing the x scale such that within `facet_wrap` the code would be:

```
facet_wrap(facets~shortname,
           scales='free_x')
```

works, but then much of the data from sites is smushed up against the x axis.

Here is the plot with the full data and free y axis:
[image]

and here is it with only the x-axis free:
[image]

Comment: Hi, @dandrews. If you only free up the x-axis scales across facets you can achieve this and optionally remove the `scale_y_continuous` scale. In `facet_wrap` set `scales = "free_x"`.

Comment: @Seth should make that an answer

Comment: @Seth nice solution here thank you. I do have a need for the y scale to also be free however. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Original answer

We can selectively free only the x-axis across `facets`. The panels will share a common y-axis, and any panel with only points at 0 will still be constrained to the range of your other data.

In `facet_wrap`, set `scales = "free_x"`, and you may remove `scale_y_continuous`.

```r
library(tidyverse)


ggplot(dat) +
  geom_point(aes(x=date,y=result,color=param_name),
             pch=19) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(element_blank()) +
  facet_wrap(facets = ~shortname,
             scales = 'free_x')  +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = '%y') +
  theme(legend.position = 'none') +
  xlab('Year') +
  ylab(expression(paste('Total Phosphorus (',mu,'/g/l)')))
```

[image]

### Updated answer

Using `ggh4x` it is possible to specify scales per facet, and the package offers a [few ways](https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/Facets.html#position-scales) to approach this.

For this example, I added some fake data to the provided example, which I include towards the end.

I first create a list of `shortnames` that I'll want to apply the y-axis limits to. In the `ggplot` function, the added `scale_y_facet` is where I'm applying a specified `limit`. I chose to use the full range of `result`, but you could adjust that as needed.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggh4x)

zero_dat <- dat %>%
  filter(sum(abs(result)) == 0, .by = shortname) %>% pull(shortname)

ggplot(dat) +
  geom_point(aes(x=date,y=result,color=param_name),
             pch=19) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(element_blank()) +
  facet_wrap(facets = ~shortname,
             scales = 'free')  +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = '%y') +
  scale_y_facet(
    shortname %in% zero_dat,
    limits = range(dat$result)) +
  theme(legend.position = 'none') +
  xlab('Year') +
  ylab(expression(paste('Total Phosphorus (',mu,'/g/l)')))
```

[image]

### Data

```
dat <- structure(list(result = c(0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 
                                 5, 10, 0), date = structure(c(7755, 7769, 7783, 7796, 7832, 7888, 
                                                               7888, 841, 7755, 8160, 8192, 8770, 9494), class = "Date"), param_name = c("TP_mgL", 
                                                                                                                                         "TP_mgL", "TP_mgL", "TP_mgL", "TP_mgL", "TP_mgL", "TP_mgL", "TP_mgL", 
                                                                                                                                         "TP_mgL", "TP_mgL", "TP_mgL", "TP_mgL", "TP_mgL"), shortname = c("Black R. Boonville", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                          "Black R. Boonville", "Black R. Boonville", "Black R. Boonville", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                          "Black R. Boonville", "Black R. Boonville", "Black R. Boonville", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                          "Independence R.", "Fake Data", "Fake Data", "Fake Data", "Fake Data", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                          "Fake Data")), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "data.frame"), na.action = structure(c(`4` = 4L, `5` = 5L, `7` = 7L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   `8` = 8L, `9` = 9L, `11` = 11L, `12` = 12L, `13` = 13L, `14` = 14L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   `21` = 21L, `23` = 23L, `24` = 24L, `25` = 25L, `27` = 27L, `32` = 32L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   `36` = 36L, `53` = 53L, `54` = 54L, `55` = 55L, `57` = 57L, `58` = 58L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   `60` = 60L, `61` = 61L, `64` = 64L, `65` = 65L, `68` = 68L, `69` = 69L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   `70` = 70L, `72` = 72L, `73` = 73L, `85` = 85L, `104` = 104L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   `105` = 105L, `109` = 109L, `110` = 110L, `123` = 123L, `127` = 127L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   `129` = 129L, `130` = 130L, `135` = 135L, `136` = 136L, `137` = 137L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   `138` = 138L, `141` = 141L, `143` = 143L, `144` = 144L, `145` = 145L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   `146` = 146L, `151` = 151L, `153` = 153L, `154` = 154L, `155` = 155L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   `156` = 156L, `157` = 157L, `161` = 161L, `164` = 164L, `165` = 165L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   `166` = 166L, `172` = 172L, `178` = 178L, `179` = 179L, `184` = 184L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   `208` = 208L, `209` = 209L, `257` = 257L, `264` = 264L, `268` = 268L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   `287` = 287L, `292` = 292L, `293` = 293L, `295` = 295L, `296` = 296L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   `297` = 297L, `304` = 304L, `320` = 320L, `329` = 329L, `330` = 330L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   `331` = 331L, `332` = 332L, `333` = 333L, `334` = 334L, `335` = 335L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   `336` = 336L, `337` = 337L, `338` = 338L, `339` = 339L, `340` = 340L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   `341` = 341L, `343` = 343L, `344` = 344L, `349` = 349L, `350` = 350L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   `351` = 351L, `365` = 365L, `371` = 371L, `374` = 374L, `378` = 378L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   `383` = 383L, `390` = 390L, `391` = 391L, `397` = 397L, `400` = 400L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   `401` = 401L, `402` = 402L, `410` = 410L, `412` = 412L, `413` = 413L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   `414` = 414L, `415` = 415L, `416` = 416L, `417` = 417L, `418` = 418L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   `419` = 419L, `421` = 421L, `422` = 422L, `424` = 424L, `425` = 425L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   `430` = 430L, `431` = 431L, `446` = 446L, `451` = 451L, `452` = 452L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   `457` = 457L, `458` = 458L, `459` = 459L, `463` = 463L, `470` = 470L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   `480` = 480L, `493` = 493L, `494` = 494L, `496` = 496L, `498` = 498L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   `499` = 499L, `500` = 500L, `501` = 501L, `506` = 506L, `507` = 507L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   `508` = 508L, `512` = 512L, `513` = 513L, `514` = 514L, `515` = 515L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   `516` = 516L, `539` = 539L, `563` = 563L, `564` = 564L, `565` = 565L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   `569` = 569L, `570` = 570L, `571` = 571L, `574` = 574L, `575` = 575L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   `581` = 581L, `587` = 587L, `593` = 593L, `600` = 600L, `605` = 605L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   `610` = 610L, `750` = 750L, `761` = 761L, `776` = 776L, `837` = 837L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   `855` = 855L, `861` = 861L, `881` = 881L), class = "omit"))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a nice solution as I posed the question. In my effort to simplify I omitted that there are data which maybe not require, but it is nice to have the y axis free so that we may visualize better data that are near zero. I added an update to the question. If you've any suggestions that keep the y axis free I'm all ears! Maybe its not possible in the current ggplot environment.

Comment: Hi @dandrews. Please see the updated part of the answer for a, admittedly complicated, way to customize scales by facet.

Comment: I saw this as an option, but the version I saw was going through one by one. This solution of breaking out those sites with only 0 in the data seems to be the best option at the moment. Cheers